# Getting Error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) when building REST API's with Flask

Tags: python, marshmallow

Receiving this error when executing a simple GET request via postman.  The following is the  API call and its failing on `author_schema.dump(fetched)`.

I am following the examples in Building REST APIs with Flask - the book is from 2019 so I assume I am encountering possible issue with dependencies.

The following are the versions that I currently have:

- flask_marshmallow -> 0.14.0
- flask_sqlalchemy -> 2.5.1 flask -> 2.0.1
- marshmallow_sqlalchemy -> 0.26.1
- marshmallow 3.13.0

I have condensed the code into a single file to share:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_marshmallow.sqla import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///author_book_publisher.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())

class AuthorSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema.Meta):
        model = Author

    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    first_name = fields.Str(required=True)
    last_name = fields.Str(required=True)
    created = fields.Str(dump_only=True)

@app.route('/api/authors', methods=['GET'])
def get_author_list():
    fetched = Author.query.all()
    author_schema = AuthorSchema(many=True, only=('first_name', 'last_name', 'id'))
    authors, error = author_schema.dump(fetched)
    return {"authors": authors}
    # return response_with(resp.SUCCESS_200, value={"authors": authors})
```

Comment: `author_schema.dump()` doesn't return anything. Why are you assigning it to variables?

Comment: In all documentation i have seen: Serialize objects by passing them to your schema’s dump method, which returns the formatted result. schema = UserSchema()
result = schema.dump(user)
pprint(result)
# {"name": "Monty",
#  "email": "monty@python.org",
#  "created_at": "2014-08-17T14:54:16.049594+00:00"}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `dump()` was changed to return a single value and throw an exception for errors instead of returning a 2-tuple.

```py
from marshmallow.exceptions import ValidationError

#...

try:
    authors = author_schema.dump(fetched)
except ValidationError as error:
    # handle error
    pass
return {"authors": authors}
```

> Changed in version 3.0.0b7: This method returns the serialized data
> rather than a (data, errors) duple. A ValidationError is raised if obj
> is invalid.

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.dump

Comment: Thanks Ian.  The exception isn't happening anymore but for some reason the json is empty when running from postman.  Need to figure why the db query isn't working.  Appreciate the help.